# In Dynamics CRM Online How do I add the Family Hierarchy to the filter options on the Price List Items Lookup Records Search Form

Tags: dynamics-crm-online

We have a large product catalog with products grouped under product families.
This is great as we can easily see the products hierarchy.

The problem is that when we create an opportunity it is very difficult to just search for a list of products that fall under one product family.

On the Opportunities form is there a way to modify the Price List Items "Look Up Records" search form to allow the user to filter the price list items by a product family?

Currently the Search form says

```
Look for: Price List Items
Look in: Price List Items in Entity Price List
Search:
```

Is there a way to add another search field such as Product Family to the filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users should be able to simply filter by typing into *Search* using wildcard (*) if needed.

You can add predefined filters, but that would require some sort of pre-selection of the product family.

An alternative could be to provide System Views for each Product Family (*Look in:*) but they come with the caveat that the filter condition for the Product Family will not work when the View is transferred from a development system to your production system because your Product Group records will have different Ids there.

A workaround to this can be to filter on the Product Group name, which should be consistent across systems/organizations.

Maybe you could add a rough description of your Product Hierarchy including number of items.

Comment: Using wildcards means the person needs to know the terms to search for, with a large product catalogue this can be difficult. I have thought about adding a field for Product Family on the Opportunity and then create a view for Product Line Items, but really not sure how to do this. Don't think a System view for each product family is good because of the Id's changing and maintaining them.

Comment: What do you mean by adding a filter on the Product Group name? Sorry I am new to Dynamics CRM.

Comment: If you create a field for Product Family, you can use it to apply a [Custom Filter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334266.aspx#BKMK_addCustomFilter) on your Product Line Items.

Comment: Is there anyway to modify the Look Up Records search form to add search fields or criteria. Anyway using javascript or the SDK?

Comment: No, you need to gather this criteria in your Opportunity form [and attach a filter as described here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334266.aspx#BKMK_addCustomFilter). This is what I meant by *"... require some sort of pre-selection..."*, for example an OptionSet, but I expect this would result in a big list in your case. You could invent some Meta Product Families to created grouped filters.